# Gregorian calendar midnight time not giving a round number

Tags: java, date

This code snippet

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.set(2013, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 6, 0, 0, 0);
long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

results in `time == 1383696000628`.

Where the heck is it getting those last 628 milliseconds from?

I'm using Java 6.

Comment: `cal.set(int, int, int, int, int, int)` does not set the milliseconds

Comment: oh snap. Thanks. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calendar.set(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) does not change MILLISECOND field, its API says

Sets the values for the fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. Previous values of other fields are retained. If this is not desired, call clear() first.

Answer (score 3):

`cal.set(int, int, int, int, int, int)` does not set the milliseconds.

Therefore, the `Calendar` instance still contains the `milliseconds` from its creation time.

You can use `GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`, although you would loose the locale, or `cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)` to remove the millis.

### Edit

As suggested by Jonathan Drapeau in the comment below, you can also call `cal.clear()` to remove all fields before calling `set`